# 1st function property

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I don't get an example exercise from Susanna Epp's Discrete math and applications.

> In Example 1.3.2 the circle relation C was defined as follows: For all
>   (x, y) ∈ R × R, (x, y) ∈ C means that x^2 + y^2 = 1. Is C a function? If
>   it is, find C(0) and C(1).

Next she says

> To see why C does not satisfy
>   property (1), observe that there are many real numbers x such that (x,
>   y) doesn't belong to C for any y. ... For instance, when x = 2, there is no real number y so that
>   x^2 + y^2 = 2^2 + y^2 = 4 + y^2 = 1

where the function property (1) is

> For every element x in A, there is an element y in B such that (x, y) ∈ F.

*C* is a subset of ordered pairs constrained by the equation `x^2 + y^2 = 1` and it doesn't include any ordered pairs where *x = 2*. For every *x* on the graph there is at least one *y*. I understand why it doesn't meet the 2nd function property, but why doesn't it satisfy the 1st?

**Update** I didn't mention the property 2 which is:

> For all elements x in A and y and z in B, if (x, y) ∈ F and (x, z) ∈ F, then y = z.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument shows that $C$ is not a function *with domain* $\mathbb{R}$; it could still potentially be a function with a different domain.

It's hard to answer your question because you don't say what "property 2" is. I assume it is "for every $x$ in $A$, there is a *unique* $y$ in $B$ such that $(x,y)\in F$" (If it isn't you should edit your question to include the properties. We don't have all textbooks lying around).

Can you find an $x\in C$ so that there exist $y_1\neq y_2$ with both $(x,y_1)$ and $(x,y_2)$ in $C$? If so, then $C$ fails to have the properties of a function.